# Shared Memory InterProcessCommunication.jl

Tags: linux, julia, posix, ipc, shared-memory

I would like to use Shared Memory in my applications, but I am struggling to find an example/documentation for how to use it. I am using InterProcessCommunication.jl.

I have two programs, AppWriter.jl, and AppReader.jl. AppWriter will create and write to shared memory, then I want AppReader.jl to detect the change and print the info in the array. Would I use semaphores for this?

I am also planning to use Julia to python as well, hence why I don't use sharedarrays.jl.

```
using InterProcessCommunication

function main()
    id = "/myid"
    len = 4096
    x = SharedMemory(id, len; perms=0o600, volatile=true)
    x[1] = 1
    print(x)
    print(x[1])
end
main()
```

(The id has a '/' in it to use POSIX.)

Gives this error:

```
LoadError: MethodError: no method matching setindex!(::SharedMemory{String}, ::Int64, ::Int64)
```

Comment: if you want to share an array, use [Shared Array](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/SharedArrays/) that's part of the stdlibs. The shared memory is lower level object you can't index it.

Comment: What if I want to do julia to python e.g.?

Comment: use PyCall.jl would be the best shot